# Pharo: "Refactoring" window cannot be closed, moved, cancelled

Tags: pharo

I tried to remove a class from one of my packages and got a "Refactoring" window which is impossible to close (no "red-yellow-green" buttons on top-left, i'm on Mac), or move. The "Cancel" button below has no effect, nor the "Apply" one. How do i get rid of this window? I can only resize it.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPpSP.png)

Thanks a lot for your help,
Richard

Answer (score 2):

Windows are objects (as everything else). So you can send messages to them. In this case you could get all of them by inspecting

```
SystemWindow allSubInstances
```

Once you locate the window you want to close, you can send it the message `#close`.

You could also go further and see how other windows add the close button and add that code to the one that lacks it.

---

You can also try

```
namesakes := World windowsSatisfying: [:w | w labelString = aString].
namesakes size = 1 ifTrue: [namesakes anyOne close]
```

where `aString` is the name of the window you want to close.

Comment: Thanks Leandro. As I did not find how to select a particular window, i closed all of them

Comment: I closed all of them at the collection level. I tried to close one by its title but that didn't work.

Comment: Please, be more specific. What do you mean "didn't work"?

Comment: Well i couldn't find out how close a particular window object from the "SystemWindow allSubInstances" list, i tried to close one item by using its name first ("Mini IMDB" found in "a SpWindow(253324032) named: Mini IMDB") then by the full description "a SpWindow(253324032) named: Mini IMDB" etc. but obviously that couldn't work because that weren't objects so i used allSubInstancesDo: #close but I should have used some code like:                                                        SystemWindow allSubInstancesDo:
 [:sw |  (sw labelString = 'Mini IMDB')
    ifTrue: [ sw close. ]
 ]

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: SystemWindow allSubInstancesDo:
 [:sw |  (sw labelString = 'Untitled window')
    ifTrue: [ sw close. ]
 ]  works for me

Comment: And your code too (if you change "label" into "labelString")  Thank you.